# How do I create a borderbody in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to create a 3D Kite game in SceneKit, and I do not want my nodes to leave the screen.

I know how to create a border body in SpriteKit.

How do I do the same in SceneKit?

Answer (score 0):

### Use SCNLookAtConstraint

This constraint orients a node to always point toward a specified other node. You can use a `look-at` constraint to ensure that your camera or light fixture always follow the movement of a character. To attach constraints to an SCNNode object, use its constraints property.

Here's code snippet:

```
cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 5, 0)  
cubeScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let box = SCNBox(width: 5, height: 5, length: 5, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
cubeScene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

// constraint for camera
let target = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: boxNode)
target.gimbalLockEnabled = YES
cameraNode.constraints = [target]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in collision detection of SceneKit.

In particular, give your nodes a physicsbody with a proper categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask. Place your nodes inside a concave sphere or box with which they can collide.

See [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/932-how-to-make-a-game-like-can-knockdown)